# no partitions grub error from a dual boot from windows seven after deleting the Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I deleted the Ubuntu partitions from window seven then I restarted the machine but it wont start up but I cant get back to windows seven.Instead I get a no partition grub rescue> error.I cant even get to the bios options because when I immediately switch on the computer I get the error window.I can't do anything.I deleted the partition because I wanted to uninstall it from the dual boot the install it in a virtual box inside windows.The problem is that when I switch on my Toshiba satellite laptop I immediately get the error that there is no such partition grub error.I can't do anything but just look at the no such partition grub rescue on the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted your Ubuntu partition it corrupted the boot-loader (Grub). If you are going to go back to a strictly Windows environment then you need to repair the MBR (Master Boot Record) MBR and Grub perform the same function in that they look for a OS. Here is a guide on repairing a MBR http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html Why may I ask did you delete the partition?